# IonicIsapiRewriter doesn't work on Windows 2008 but does in Vista

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2008, iirf

I am migrating my sites from a Windows 2003 server to Windows 2008 however the url rewriting application simply doesnt work when set up on the Windows 2008.

Any ideas? I just get 404's instead of it trying to rewrite the url.

I have tried using MS Urlrewriting module but it doesnt appear to work either as I have to use the app in Integrated mode as its a bit old school

Any more ideas?! Could be server is 64-bit and my laptop isnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out. What I needed to do was

"Enable 32-Bit Application" in the Advanced Settings on my App Pool

Answer (score 1):

[Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF/) states it works on

> "Windows Server 2008 with IIS7"

What excatly doesn't work?

Comment: Anything, I add it as an asapi filter just like I do in Vista but it doesnt work, I simply get 404's as if I hadnt even installed it, even tried restarting iis